# Group a sorted array based on the difference between current and previous elements

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array sorted in ascending order:

```
const arr=[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 17, 18]
```

I have to group it, in such a way so that:

1. Elements within a group have a difference of `1` or less
2. Each group element should have more than one element to be considered valid

Based on the above conditions, the expected output would be:

```
const resultArr=[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [5, 6, 7],
  [17, 18]//each has more than one element
]
```

Ok, at this point my brain pretty much stopped..

What I tried was:

```
let prev = arr[0];
const resultArr = [prev];
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const curr = arr[i];

  if (curr - prev <= 1) {
    resultArr.push(curr);
  } else {
    resultArr.shift();
  }

  prev = curr;
}
```

Help very much appreciated!

Edit: would be great to have solution without `reduce` function

Comment: Can there be duplicate values in the array?

Comment: @Nick no duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the predecessor and add the value to the last array of the result set or check if the next value is valid, then add a new group to the result set.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 17, 18],
    result = array.reduce((result, value, index, array) => {
        if (array[index - 1] + 1 === value) result[result.length - 1].push(value);
        else if (value + 1 === array[index + 1]) result.push([value]);
        return result;
    }, []);    

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

One with a classic loop.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 17, 18],
    result = [];


for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    let value = array[index];

    if (array[index - 1] + 1 === value) {
        result[result.length - 1].push(value);
    } else if (value + 1 === array[index + 1]) {
        result.push([value]);
    }
}    

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: is there a non-reduce version by any chance? :) and wow was quite fast!

Comment: you type at a god speed lol!! I think it is missing `2.` clause check

Comment: no, because the second check looks ahead and it comes at least to another iteration.